# Does Xenial provide boost asio only at version 1.10, even though other boost libraries are 1.58?

Tags: package-management, libraries

Not sure if I get it correctly. If I understand https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libboost-dev correctly:

- libboost* packages are 1.58;
- However, asio is not in boost packages; rather, we have libasio* packages;
- Which are 1.10 only.

Am I missing something? If not, why is asio provided outside of boost packages and with a lower version?

EDIT: Wow. Even bionic provides libasio 1.10 only. I must be missing something. Is asio provided somewhere under libboost*, only I am blind?

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing libasio as being part of boost. It is a separate library. The boost asio header is included in the versioned `libboost1.58-dev` package in xenial.